# Storing MATLAB structs in Java objects

Tags: java, matlab, hashmap

I'm using Java HashMap in MATLAB

```
h = java.util.HashMap;
```

And while strings, arrays and matrices works seemlessly with it

```
h.put(5, 'test');

h.put(7, magic(4));
```

Structs do not

```
h=java.util.HashMap;
st.val = 7;
h.put(7, st);

??? No method 'put' with matching signature found for class 'java.util.HashMap'.
```

**What would be the easiest/most elegant way to make it work for structs?**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to ensure that the data passed from MATLAB to Java can be properly converted. See MATLAB's [External Interfaces document](http://www.mathworks.com/help/pdf_doc/matlab/apiext.pdf) for the conversion matrix of which types get converted to which other types.

MATLAB treats most data as pass-by-value (with the exception of classes with handle semantics), and there doesn't appear to be a way to wrap a structure in a Java interface. But you could use another HashMap to act like a structure, and convert MATLAB structures to HashMaps (with an obvious warning for multiple-level structures, function handles, + other beasts that don't play well with the MATLAB/Java data conversion process).

```
function hmap = struct2hashmap(S)
if ((~isstruct(S)) || (numel(S) ~= 1))
    error('struct2hashmap:invalid','%s',...
          'struct2hashmap only accepts single structures');
end

hmap = java.util.HashMap;
for fn = fieldnames(S)'
    % fn iterates through the field names of S
    % fn is a 1x1 cell array
    fn = fn{1};
    hmap.put(fn,getfield(S,fn));
end
```

a possible use case:

```
>> M = java.util.HashMap;
>> M.put(1,'a');
>> M.put(2,33);
>> s = struct('a',37,'b',4,'c','bingo')

s = 

    a: 37
    b: 4
    c: 'bingo'

>> M.put(3,struct2hashmap(s));
>> M

M =

{3.0={a=37.0, c=bingo, b=4.0}, 1.0=a, 2.0=33.0}

>>
```

(an exercise for the reader: change this to work recursively for structure members which themselves are structures)

Answer (score 5):

Matlab R2008b and newer have a containers.Map class that provides HashMap-like functionality on native Matlab datatypes, so they'll work with structs, cells, user-defined Matlab objects, and so on.

```
% Must initialize with a dummy value to allow numeric keys
m = containers.Map(0, 0, 'uniformValues',false);
% Remove dummy entry
m.remove(0);

m(5) = 'test';
m(7) = magic(4);
m(9) = struct('foo',42, 'bar',1:3);
m(5), m(7), m(9) % get values back out
```

Comment: But as far as I can tell they are not appropriate as arguments to a Java `Map<>` parameter?

Comment: Correct, they are not. This is only a solution if you want to go with all-Matlab datatypes instead of a Java `Map`, and avoid the complexities of Java-to-Matlab conversion. If you need to interoperate with other Java code that takes a `Map`, this won't work.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with Java HashMaps, but could you try using a cell array to store the data instead of a struct?

```
h = java.util.HashMap;
carr = {7, 'hello'};
h.put(7, carr);

% OR

h = java.util.HashMap;
st.val = 7;
h.put(7, struct2cell(st));
```