# Hash tables in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, hashtable

Does MATLAB have any support for hash tables?

---

### Some background

I am working on a problem in Matlab that requires a scale-space representation of an image. To do this I create a 2-D Gaussian filter with variance `sigma*s^k` for `k` in some range., and then I use each one in turn to filter the image.  Now, I want some sort of mapping from `k` to the filtered image.

If `k` were always an integer, I'd simply create a 3D array such that:

```
arr[k] = <image filtered with k-th guassian>
```

However, `k` is not necessarily an integer, so I can't do this.  What I thought of doing was keeping an array of `k`s such that:

```
arr[find(array_of_ks_ = k)] = <image filtered with k-th guassian>
```

Which seems pretty good at first thought, except I will be doing this lookup potentially a few thousand times with about 20 or 30 values of `k`, and I fear that this will hurt performance.

I wonder if I wouldn't be better served doing this with a hash table of some sort so that I would have a lookup time that is O(1) instead of O(n).

---

Now, I know that I shouldn't optimize prematurely, and I may not have this problem at all, but remember, this is just the background, and there may be cases where this is really the best solution, regardless of whether it is the best solution for *my* problem.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Matlab does not have support for hashtables. **EDIT** Until r2010a, that is; see [@Amro](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3591942/hash-tables-in-matlab/3592050#3592050)'s answer.

To speed up your look-ups, you can drop the `find`, and use [LOGICAL INDEXING](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/math/f1-85462.html).

```
arr{array_of_ks==k} = <image filtered with k-th Gaussian>
```

or

```
arr(:,:,array_of_ks==k) = <image filtered with k-th Gaussian>
```

However, in all my experience with Matlab, I've *never* had a lookup be a bottleneck.

---

To speed up your specific problem, I suggest to either use incremental filtering

```
arr{i} = GaussFilter(arr{i-1},sigma*s^(array_of_ks(i)) - sigma*s^(array_of_ks(i-1)))
```

assuming `array_of_ks` is sorted in ascending order, and GaussFilter calculates the filter mask size based on the variance (and uses, 2 1D filters, of course), or you can filter in Fourier Space, which is especially useful for large images and if the variances are spaced evenly (which they most likely aren't unfortunately).

Answer (score 122):

Consider using MATLAB's map class: [containers.Map](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/map-containers.html). Here is a brief overview:

- Creation:

  ```
  >> keys = {'Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', ...
    'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec', 'Annual'};

  >> values = {327.2, 368.2, 197.6, 178.4, 100.0,  69.9, ...
    32.3,  37.3,  19.0,  37.0,  73.2, 110.9, 1551.0};

  >> rainfallMap = containers.Map(keys, values)

  rainfallMap = 
    containers.Map handle
    Package: containers

    Properties:
          Count: 13
        KeyType: 'char'
      ValueType: 'double'
    Methods, Events, Superclasses
  ```
- Lookup:

  ```
  x = rainfallMap('Jan');
  ```
- Assign:

  ```
  rainfallMap('Jan') = 0;
  ```
- Add:

  ```
  rainfallMap('Total') = 999;
  ```
- Remove:

  ```
  rainfallMap.remove('Total')
  ```
- Inspect:

  ```
  values = rainfallMap.values;
  keys = rainfallMap.keys;
  sz = rainfallMap.size;
  ```
- Check key:

  ```
  if rainfallMap.isKey('Today')
      ...
  end
  ```

Comment: Wow, I didn't know that! +1. Do you know whether they're much faster than logical indexing?

Comment: Containers.Map was added in MATLAB 7.7 (R2008b) see http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/rn/brqyzax-1.html . New in R2010a is a constructor to specify key type as well as value type. 
M = containers.Map('KeyType', kType, 'ValueType', vType)

Comment: @Jonas: I haven't used them extensively, it would be interesting to see how they compare against using logical indexing for lookup..

Comment: @zellus: my bad, I guess I only noticed them recently :)

Comment: @zellus,@amro: Isn't it annoying how there is no history of the commands in Matlab?

Comment: @Jonas: Good point, a command history might be interesting. Overall the documentation is outstanding, compared with other products. I was waiting for the new constructor, therefore I knew that the maps where available before R2010a.

Comment: Lookup: rainfallMap('Jan'); Assign: rainfallMap('Jan') = 'zero'; Inspect: rainfallMap.values; rainfallMap.keys; rainfallMap.size; Check key: rainfallMap.isKey('Today');

Comment: As of MATLAB R2022b, [`dictionary`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/releases/R2022b/matlab/ref/dictionary.html) is now recommended over [`containers.Map`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/containers.map.html). I have [added an answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77504674/11082165) on how to use `dictionary`

Answer (score 26):

Matlab R2008b (7.7)’s new containers.Map class is a scaled-down Matlab version of the [java.util.Map](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) interface. It has the added benefit of seamless integration with all Matlab types ([Java Maps cannot handle Matlab structs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/436852/storing-matlab-structs-in-java-objects) for example) as well as the ability since Matlab 7.10 (R2010a) to [specify data types](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/containers_map.html).

Serious Matlab implementations requiring key-value maps/dictionaries should still use Java’s Map classes ([java.util.EnumMap](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/EnumMap.html), [HashMap](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html), [TreeMap](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html), [LinkedHashMap](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html) or [Hashtable](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Hashtable.html)) to gain access to their larger functionality if not performance. Matlab versions earlier than R2008b have no real alternative in any case and must use the Java classes.

A potential limitation of using Java Collections is their inability to contain non-primitive Matlab types such as structs. To overcome this, either down-convert the types (e.g., using struct2cell or programmatically), or create a separate Java object that will hold your information and store this object in the Java Collection.

You may also be interested to examine a pure-Matlab object-oriented (class-based) Hashtable implementation, which is [available on the File Exchange](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/26778).

Comment: Another Matlab class-based implementation posted today: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/28586

Answer (score 19):

You could use java for it.

In matlab:

```
dict = java.util.Hashtable;
dict.put('a', 1);
dict.put('b', 2);
dict.put('c', 3);
dict.get('b')
```

But you would have to do some profiling to see if it gives you a speed gain I guess...

Answer (score 12):

It's a little clugey, but I'm surprised nobody has suggested using structs.  You can access any struct field by variable name as `struct.(var)` where `var` can be any variable and will resolve appropriately.

```
dict.a = 1;
dict.b = 2;

var = 'a';

display( dict.(var) ); % prints 1
```

Comment: It would break if you use a number as a fieldname: `dict.('2')`: http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/matlab_prog/br04bw6-38.html#br1v5bu-1

Comment: Also, the variables have to be integers: `dict.(['k',num2str(1)])` works, but `dict.(['k',num2str(1.1)])` fails, and if the values are integers, you can use them to index directly. It's a nice idea otherwise.

Comment: @Amro, @Jonas, fair points, if the the keys were integers you wouldn't need to use this trick (an array would make more sense)...if the keys are arbitrary floats this is a little more challenging, but I'd prefix with a letter and replace the `.` with an `_`.

Comment: The above issues with using structures can be avoided by variabilizing the strings before adding as field names: `dict.(genvarname(['k',num2str(1.1)]))`

Answer (score 2):

MATLAB 2022b added the [`dictionary`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/dictionary.html) object. A complete usage guide can be found under [Language Fundamentals > Data Types > Dictionaries](https://www.mathworks.com/help/releases/R2022b/matlab/dictionary.html) in the MATLAB documentation.

`dictionary` is now recommended over the old [`containers.Map`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/containers.map.html). Quoting the documentation for `containers.Map`:

> [`dictionary`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/dictionary.html) is recommended over `containers.Map` because it accepts more data types as keys and values and provides better performance. (since R2022b)

From the [R2022b Release Notes](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/release-notes.html#rngroup_R2022b):

> In almost all use cases, `dictionary` performs faster than `containers.Map`.

For `containers.Map` usage, see [Amro's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3592050/11082165).

#### Construction

Dictionaries can be constructed from a set of initial entries by passing key and value arrays with an equal number of entries:

```
% From key and value arrays
>> d = dictionary(["a", "b", "c"], [1, 2, 3])
d = 
  dictionary (string ⟼ double) with 3 entries:

    "a" ⟼ 1
    "b" ⟼ 2
    "c" ⟼ 3
```

Alternatively, initial entries can be provided as key-value pairs:

```
% Using Name=Value syntax (string keys only)
>> d = dictionary(a=1, b=2, c=3)  
d = 
  dictionary (string ⟼ double) with 3 entries:

    "a" ⟼ 1
    "b" ⟼ 2
    "c" ⟼ 3

>> squares = dictionary(2, 4, 3, 9, 4, 16)
squares =
  dictionary (double ⟼ double) with 3 entries:
    2 ⟼ 4
    3 ⟼ 9
    4 ⟼ 16
```

To create an unconfigured dictionary, you can use `dictionary` without any inputs:

```
>> d_unconfigured = dictionary
d_unconfigured =
  dictionary with unset key and value types.
```

The dictionary will become configured once you assign an entry.

To construct an empty dictionary with pre-configured key and value types, you can use [`configureDictionary`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/dictionary.configuredictionary.html) (R2023b or later):

```
>> d_empty = configureDictionary("string", "double")
d_empty =
  dictionary (string ⟼ double) with no entries.
```

#### Lookup

Single key:

```
>> d("a")
ans =
     1
```

Simultaneously look-up an array of keys:

```
>> k = [ "a" "b"
         "b" "c" ];
>> d(k)
ans =
     1     2
     2     3
```

Error on invalid key lookup:

```
>> d("bad key")
Error using  () 
Key not found. 

>> d(123)
Error using  () 
Key not found.
```

MATLAB R2023b introduced the [`lookup`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/dictionary.lookup.html) function, which allows you to specify a fallback value:

```
>> d.lookup("a", FallbackValue=nan)
ans =
     1

>> d.lookup("missing", FallbackValue=nan)
ans =
   NaN
```

#### Assignment

```
>> d("new") = 10
d =
  dictionary (string ⟼ double) with 4 entries:
    "a"   ⟼ 1
    "b"   ⟼ 2
    "c"   ⟼ 3
    "new" ⟼ 10
```

Values are automatically marshaled into the value type if a conversion is possible. If no conversion is possible, and error is emitted:

```
d("new") = "123"  % Note: string instead of double
d =
  dictionary (string ⟼ double) with 4 entries:
    "a"   ⟼ 1
    "b"   ⟼ 2
    "c"   ⟼ 3
    "new" ⟼ 123

>> d("new") = @sum
Error using  () 
Unable to use 'function_handle' as value for dictionary with 'double' value type.
Caused by:
    Conversion to double from function_handle is not possible
```

#### Deletion

Keys can be deleted by assigning an empty array `[]`:

```
>> d("a") = []
d =
  dictionary (string ⟼ double) with 2 entries:
    "b" ⟼ 2
    "c" ⟼ 3
```

Arrays of keys can also be used on the left-hand side, just as seen under Assignment above.

MATLAB 2023b introduced the [`remove`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/dictionary.remove.html) function, which behaves identically to assigning `[]`:

```
>> d.remove("a")
ans =
  dictionary (string ⟼ double) with 2 entries:
    "b" ⟼ 2
    "c" ⟼ 3
```

#### Size

Number of entries:

```
>> d.numEntries
ans =
     3
```

#### Extracting key/value collections

Key and value arrays:

```
>> d.keys
ans = 
  3×1 string array
    "a"
    "b"
    "c"

>> d.values
ans =
     1
     2
     3
```

Entries [table](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/tables.html):

```
>> d.entries
ans =
  3×2 table
    Key    Value
    ___    _____
    "a"      1  
    "b"      2  
    "c"      3
```

#### Querying types configuration

Query the key and value types:

```
>> [kt, vt] = d.types
kt = 
    "string"
vt = 
    "double"
```

Checking whether the dictionary has configured key and value types:

```
>> d.isConfigured
ans =
  logical
   1
```

Dictionaries constructed without any initial entries start unconfigured:

```
>> d2 = dictionary
d2 =
  dictionary with unset key and value types.

>> d2.isConfigured
ans =
  logical
   0

>> [kt, vt] = d2.types
kt = 
    <missing>
vt = 
    <missing>
```

Unconfigured dictionaries become configured as soon as an entry is assigned:

```
>> d2("key") = "value"
d2 =
  dictionary (string ⟼ string) with 1 entry:
    "key" ⟼ "value"

>> d2.isConfigured
ans =
  logical
   1
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also take advantage of the new type "Table". You can store different types of data and get statistics out of it really easy. 
See http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/tables.html for more info.