# How do I build a map in Matlab?

Tags: matlab

I tried:

```
new_map = containers.Map('KeyType', 'double', 'ValueType', 'double')
```

but it doesn't work.  I need a map from vector of doubles to double.

```
.??? No constructor 'containers.Map' with matching signature found.
```

Comment: What version of MATLAB are you using?  The containers are a recent addition to MATLAB.  They are in 2010a but I am not sure how much farther back.

Comment: check this post, especially the comment by @zellus: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3591942/hash-tables-in-matlab/3592050#3592050

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Hash tables in MATLAB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3591942/hash-tables-in-matlab)

Comment: **Note from the future**: as of MATLAB R2022b, [`dictionary`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/releases/R2022b/matlab/ref/dictionary.html) is now recommended over [`containers.Map`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/containers.map.html). See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3591942/hash-tables-in-matlab) for how to use `dictionary`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the following workaround for pre 2010a versions of matlab.

```
key1 = 1.0;
val1 = 1.0;
mapObj = containers.Map(key1, val1);
remove(mapObj, key1);
```