# How can we assign letters to numbers

Tags: matlab

I have the following:

d=[1 2 3 4 5 6 7]

I want Matlab to assign a day name to every number by doing a loop or

any suitable method as follows:

1 =tuesday

2=wednesday

.

.

.

7=monday

the results I am aiming to get after running the program is :

the Matlab window asks the user to enter a number from 1 to 7

n=('enter a number from 1 to 7')

then,

if we enter ,for example, 4 , this means that the printed result is: Friday

or

if we entered , for example , 7, this means that the printed result is: Monday

and so on

Is there any way to do this

regards

Comment: Yes, there are multiple ways to do this.  What have you tried and where are you having problems?

Comment: Have you looked at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_programming

Answer (score 5):

You could use a [cell array](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/matlab_prog/br04bw6-98.html), which allows you to store an array of text strings. The curly bracket is the key:

```
>> weekdays = {'Mon', 'Tues', 'Weds', 'Thurs', 'Fri', 'Sat', 'Sun'};
>> weekdays{4}

ans =

Thurs
```

**Edit:** You can get the relevant number from the user by using MATLAB's [input](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/input.html) function:

```
n = input('Enter your number:');
disp(weekdays{n})
```

Comment: Good approach as long as you don't want to change (add, remove) elements. Which will be a rare case for weekdays.

Answer (score 1):

Using a map might be one approach:

```
weekDays = containers.Map({1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7} , ...
{'tuesday', 'wednesday', 'thursday', 'friday', 'saturday', 'sunday'});

number = input('enter a number from 1 to 7');
disp(sprintf('You did choose %s\n', weekDays(number)));
```

**EDIT:**
Using the solution by Bill Cheatham you end up with

```
weekdays = {'Mon', 'Tues', 'Weds', 'Thurs', 'Fri', 'Sat', 'Sun'};
number = input('enter a number from 1 to 7');
disp(sprintf('You did choose %s\n', weekdays{number}));
```

Comment: thanks. but what is this function: containers.Map . I am using MATLAB. I think it is not defined there.regards

Comment: @g_kfupm: What version of MATLAB are you using.

Comment: @g_kfupm: it's Java, but there is a Java interpreter in MATLAB, and it works as advertised.

Comment: @André Caron: Sorry for disagreeing, but containers.Map is part of the MATLAB commands. As MATLAB allows Java scripting, you might use a  Java hashmap as well.

Comment: Containers.Map was added in MATLAB 7.7 (R2008b) as mentioned in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3591942/hash-tables-in-matlab/3592050#3592050

Comment: @g_kfupm: Then http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4073060/how-can-we-assign-letters-to-numbers/4073267#4073267 by Bill Cheatham might be an option, or switching to python :-).

Comment: zellus: but what Bill Cheatham has done is by simply looking to the matrix and then extracting. Can we get it programmed automatically and show the result by simply pressing a number from 1 to 7. regards. thanks for everyone helps in this question.

Comment: @g_kfupm: I tried to give a 'full' solution in the edited section of this post, taking Bill Cheathams approach.

Comment: zellus: perfect. It works perfectly. thanks a lot , I appreciate your cooperation. Thanks to Bill Cheatham. Thanks to everyone participates to solve my problem. regards

Comment: @g_kfupm: Your welcome, just added a disp() in order to show the result.