# Overloading operators in MATLAB to emulate hash-array

Tags: matlab, hash, indexing, operator-overloading

Is it possible to overload `subsref` and `subsasgn` to allow non-integer types for index value?

```
h = Hash; #% a custom hash class to manage my data
h(100) = 'data'; #% integer is fine, if index > 0

h{'string'} #% but this fails
??? Cell contents reference from a
non-cell array object.
```

Can one hack it somehow?

---

### Exact solution:

There are several annoyances in `containers.Map`, which can be solved by making a custom class which inherits it:

```
classdef Hash < containers.Map
  # fun
end
```

In such class one can implement various types of keys (not just one!!) and convenience methods for the user operations. Also it is possible to redefine `subsref` and `subsasgn` to work with curly braces and multiple indices. Nice!

Comment: There is a built in solution too: 'Containers.Map'.Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3591942/hash-tables-in-matlab

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No need to hack. Use a struct or a [containers.Map](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/containers_map.html). They are native Matlab data structures for associative arrays. A struct is indexed by strings (with some restrictions). A containers.Map can be indexed by string, non-integer numerics, or other data types. See "help struct" and "help containers.Map". The Map uses parentheses for indexing, so its syntax looks like an array indexed by other means.

```
>> m = containers.Map(.1, 'myvalue');
>> m(.75) = 'anothervalue';
>> x = m(.1)
x =
myvalue
>>
```

Comment: Thanks! It can also be inherited if one needs more methods to add. Very nice!

Comment: +1 -- I've been using Matlab for 12 yrs and didn't know about that one.

Comment: @Jason S: Don't feel bad; it's new as of R2008b, and not well advertised in the doco or otherwise. I just stumbled across it last year.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use a [`java.util.HashMap`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html)? Matlab works fine with Java. (Although I guess that only works with data that can be marshalled into Java, so although matrices and cell arrays of matrices are OK, structs are out)

```
>> x = java.util.HashMap;
>> x.put(3, [1 2 3]);
>> x.put('Rosebud',[4 5 6; 7 8 9]);
>> x.put([2 4 6 8],'Michaelangelo'); 
>> x.get(3)

ans =

     1
     2
     3

>> x.get('Rosebud')

ans =

     4     5     6
     7     8     9

>> x.get([2 4 6 8])

ans =

     []
```

Aha: watch out for that last bit -- the equality semantics in Java for numbers and strings are straightforward, but for arrays, things get tricky, and using Java in MATLAB is a little like handling lab samples in a glove box.

If you can deal with the limitations of `java.util.HashMap` (key equality semantics, type limitations to those that can be marshalled between Java and MATLAB), use it -- otherwise you probably would have to write your own.

Comment: @Jason, Could you show an example how you would make a simple hash-array in MATLAB? I have no experience with Java

Comment: @Jason, Thanks, there are probably many advantages in the Java class. However, I wanted to avoid method calls (get/set) and to use just brackets.

Comment: @Jason, It takes a couple of minutes to make a Hash class with .get and .set methods which would work better than `java.util.HashMap`.

Comment: cool, if you don't mind, could you post? I haven't got used to the new MATLAB class syntax, + it would be a good example.

Comment: @Jason, It takes a bit more for me :) You can have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3591942/hash-tables-in-matlab There are links to MATLAB Central with ready examples.