# Fast associative arrays or maps in Matlab

Tags: matlab, performance

I need to build a *fast* **one-to-one mapping** between two large arrays of integers in Matlab. The mapping should take as input an element from a pre-defined array, e.g.:

```
in_range    = [-200   2  56   45 ... ];
```

and map it, by its index in the previous array, to the corresponding element from another pre-defined array, e.g.:

```
out_range   = [-10000 0  97   600 ... ];
```

For example, in the case above, `my_map(-200)` should output `-10000`, and `my_map(45)` should output `600`.

I need a solution that

1. Can map very large arrays (~100K elements) relatively efficiently.
2. Scales well with the bounds of `in_range` and `out_range` (i.e. their `min` and `max` values)

So far, I have solved this problem using Matlab's external interface to Java with **Java's HashMaps**, but I was wondering if there was a Matlab-native alternative.

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Hash tables in Matlab](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3591942/hash-tables-in-matlab)

Comment: The answers to the duplicate (other than mine) tell you all you need to know.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The latest versions of Matlab have [hashes](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/matlab_prog/brqqo5e-1.html).  I'm using 2007b and they aren't available, so I use [structs](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/struct.html) whenever I need a hash.  Just convert the integers to valid field names with [genvarname](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/genvarname.html).