# How to use Hash Tables (dictionaries) in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab

I need to acces data by string index, like ***table('one') %returns 1***. Is there such a data structure in MATLAB? How is it implemented?

Comment: (also cross-duplicate of http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/21130-dictionaries-of-hashtables-in-matlab)

Answer (score 55, accepted):

In recent versions of MATLAB, there's the `containers.Map` data structure. See [MATLAB Map containers](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/containers.map.html) for more. This removes some of the restrictions when using STRUCTs. For example

```
c = containers.Map
c('foo') = 1
c(' not a var name ') = 2
keys(c)
values(c)
```

Comment: **Note from the future**: as of MATLAB R2022b, [`dictionary`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/releases/R2022b/matlab/ref/dictionary.html) is now recommended over [`containers.Map`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/containers.map.html). See [the duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3591942/hash-tables-in-matlab) for how to use `dictionary`.

Answer (score 17):

A structure can be used as a sort of hash table:

```
>> foo.('one')=1

foo = 

    one: 1

>> foo.('two')=2;
>> x = 'two';
>> foo.(x)

ans =

     2
```

To query whether a structure contains a particular field (key), use `isfield`:

```
>> isfield(foo,'two')

ans =

     1
```

The disadvantage of this scheme is that only strings that are also valid Matlab variable names can be used as keys.  For instance:

```
>> foo.('_bar')=99;
??? Invalid field name: '_bar'.
```

To get around this restriction, use one of the solutions in the question linked by Oli.

Comment: Another disadvantage of this approach is that the names of the keys have to be less than `namelengthmax` (63) characters

Answer (score 0):

Just to add to the previous answers (could not comment on the other good answers) : a struct lookup like this:

```
s={};
s.abc = 1;   %insert a value in the struct, abc is your lookup hash
out = s.abc; % read it back
```

The actual read back of the value is about 10 times faster with a struct than using a container. Full test code as follows if interesting

```
function s=test_struct_lookup_hash_speed
%% test how a struct lookup speed works vs container, interesting

    s = {};  % hash table
    v = {};  % reverselookup table for testing

    nHashes = 1E4;  % vary this to see if read speed varies by size (NOT REALLY)
    nReads  = 1E6;

    fprintf('Generating hash struct of %i entries\n', nHashes);
    tic
    for i = 1:nHashes
        hashStr = md5fieldname(randi(1E8));
        s.(hashStr) = i;
        v{end+1} = hashStr;  %reverselookup
    end
    toc

    fprintf('Actual HashTable length (due to non unique hashes?): %i, and length of reverse table: %i\n',length(fieldnames(s)), length(v) );

    fprintf('Reading %i times from a random selection from the %i hashes\n', nReads, nHashes);
    vSubset = [ v(randi(nHashes,1,3))  ];

    for i = 1:length(vSubset)
       hashStr = vSubset{i};

       % measure read speed only
       tic
       for j = 1:nReads
         val = s.(hashStr);
       end
       toc

    end


    %% test CONTAINERS
    fprintf('Testing Containers\n');
    c = containers.Map;

    fprintf('Generating hash struct of %i entries\n', nHashes);
    tic
    for i = 1:nHashes
        hashStr = md5fieldname(randi(1E8));
        c(hashStr) = i;
        v{end+1} = hashStr;  %reverselookup
    end
    toc

   fprintf('Reading %i times from a random selection from the %i hashes\n', nReads, nHashes);
   vSubset = [ v(randi(nHashes,1,3))  ];

    for i = 1:length(vSubset)
       hashStr = vSubset{i};

       % measure read speed only
       tic
       for j = 1:nReads
         val = c(hashStr);
       end
       toc

    end    



    %% Get a valid fieldname (has to start with letter)   
    function h=md5fieldname(inp)
    h = ['m' hash(inp,'md5')];
    end


end
```