# Integer encoding

Tags: matlab, encoding

I am trying to figure out how to encode integers based on given parameters. For example, I am given the table:

```
integer = 0, encoding is 3294 

integer = 1, encoding is 128 

integer = 2, encoding is 2098
```

etc.

How would I go about doing this? I have looked at the function dec2bin, but it's not exactly what I need. My input would be a vector, say `x = [ 2 1 0 ]` and the output would be the vector `y = [2 0 9 8 1 2 8 3 2 9 4]`.

Any advice or help is appreciated!

Comment: You can do this by extracting individual digits from the number. Information on how to do it is given [here](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/13751)

Answer (score 3):

Encoding may not be the best word to describe this. This answer is just a direction in your search.

I would have a look at any `dictionary`, `hashtable` or `map` data structures. Code below is based on solution described in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9868400/706456)

```
c = containers.Map;
c('0') = 3294; 
c('1') = 128;
c('2') = 2098;
keys(c) 
values(c)
```

You may need to add proper usings and maybe use integers types directly to remove casts and conversion overhead.

Comment: Awesome, thank you. I will look more into the containers.Map. What if for some of the values, I wanted to assign it to a function? For example, I had a table for integers 0 through 2, but then for integers greater than 2, I want to assign it to some function example(x) = 1- example(x-2)?

Answer (score 1):

If you represent the encoding table as a cell array `enc` with two columns (each row contains an integer and its corresponding encoding string), you can use the following neat one-liner:

```
y = str2num(cell2mat(arrayfun(@(v)enc{find([enc{:, 1}] == v), 2}', x(:), 'UniformOutput', 0)))'
```

#### Explanation

The above solution actually does three things:

1. Substitutes each integer in the input vector `x` with the corresponding encoding string from `enc`:

   ```
   arrayfun(@(v)enc{find([enc{:, 1}] == v), 2}', x(:), 'UniformOutput', 0)
   ```
2. Concatenate all strings together into one column using `cell2mat`.
3. Converts it back into a numerical vector using `str2num`. `str2num` is applied on rows, so each character (digit) is treated individually.

#### Example

```
enc = {0, '3294'; 1, '128'; 2, '2098'};
x = [2, 1, 0];
y = str2num(cell2mat(arrayfun(@(v)enc{find([enc{:, 1}] == v), 2}', x(:), 'UniformOutput', 0)))'
```

The result is:

```
y =
     2     0     9     8     1     2     8     3     2     9     4
```

Comment: Thank you for the insight! What if the values were 0s and 1s? When I tried to do enc = [2, 0111101] for example, it tells me enc = 2 111101

Comment: @Abi Good point. The encoding table is numerical, and therefore leading zeros are omitted. I've fixed that (note that the encoding table `enc` is now a cell array).

Comment: Ah, I actually ended up doing switch cases instead. It was probably not very efficient (had almost 30 cases), but it works. Thank you again for the help though!