# Dictionary with string keys in matlab

Tags: matlab

I am trying to create a dictionary for which the keys are strings. I read [an example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9850007/how-to-use-hash-tables-dictionaries-in-matlab) doing this. However, in my case, I get

```
Error using containers.Map/subsasgn
Specified key type does not match the type expected for this container.
```

How is it different from the example in the link?

```
k = {}
k = [k,{'01'}];
k = [k, {'02'}];
m = containers.Map;
m(cellstr(k(1))) = 1
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`cellstr(k(1))` returns a cell type, not a string. So k{1} works:

```
k = {'01', '02'};
m = containers.Map;
m(k{1}) = 1
```

This code works for me, with MATLAB 2014b on Linux:

```
>>     k = {'01', '02'};
    m = containers.Map;
    m(k{1}) = 1

m = 

  Map with properties:

        Count: 1
      KeyType: char
    ValueType: any
```

Comment: @giulio: With the code above it works, please verify that `class(k{1})` is char.