# How to convert a String to a Matrix Matlab

Tags: matlab

Im trying to convert a String into a Matrix. So like a=1 b=2... "Space"=28. Etc.

My question is how would I convert a string to a matrix?

aka..
abc=[1,2,3]

Tried a for loop, which does convert the string into numbers.
Here is where I try to make it into a Matrix

```
String1=char(string)
String2=reshape(String1,[10,14]);
```

the error I get is
"To RESHAPE the number of elements must not change"
"String2=reshape(String1,[10,14]);

Answer (score 1):

If you need a **general coding from characters into numbers** (not necessarily ASCII):

1. Define the coding by means of a string, such that the character that appears first corresponds to number `1`, etc.
2. Use [`ismember`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ismember.html) to do the "reverse indexing" operation.

Code:

```
coding = 'abcdefghijklmnñopqrstuvwxyz .,;'; %// define coding: 'a' is 1, 'b' is 2 etc
str = 'abc xyz'; %// example text
[~, result] = ismember(str, coding);
```

In this example,

```
result =
     1     2     3    28    25    26    27
```

Comment: Doesn't `ismember` perform a linear search on the array, here? If so, I'm not sure this would scale well for a large alphabet.

Comment: @Jubobs It probably does perform a linear search on the second input, unless that second input is sorted, in which case it calls the helper mex `ismembc` or `ismembc2` functions (at least in R2010b), which deal with the sorted case more efficiently. So for large alphabets it may be slow. But in that case, how could it be done faster?

Comment: Using some kind of finite-map data structure, I suppose (like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9850007/how-to-use-hash-tables-dictionaries-in-matlab), but I haven't tested it.