# What is MATLAB equivalent of Java HashSet?

Tags: matlab

Java has [HashSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html) class which I can use to create sets and add element in constant time making it efficient to compute unique values in a list.

How can I do the same in MATLAB? Is there an equivalent native class? [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12625629/is-there-any-way-to-use-hashtables-hashmaps-in-matlab) question proposes using Java's HashSet but does not provide native class.

Comment: What's wrong with [`struct`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/struct.html)? Alternatively, you could use [`table`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/table.html).

Comment: I did not try them but what I eventually used is containers.Map  with arbitrary key value and then finally fetched the key set... I think it is similar how you are suggesting to use struct.

Comment: What do you mean by native? It goes Matlab->Java->C->Assembly->$$&%"§4. Which one do you consider native?

Answer (score -4):

Use struct in Matlab. Refer to http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/struct.html

Comment: Posting a solution as a new answer from an 3 month old comment isn't good behavior.

Comment: @Paebbels Particularly when it is an incorrect answer.