# importing containers to matlab

Tags: matlab, import

Im quite new with matlab and im trying to use the `containers.Map`, for that there is a need to import that container.

when I use the command `map = containers.Map(someKey, someValue);`, I get this error `undefined variable "containers" or class "containers.Map"`

so I tried `import containers.*` but I get the same error.

matlab looks for the container on matlab workspace.

I also read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12625629/is-there-any-way-to-use-hashtables-hashmaps-in-matlab) article and used `java.util.HashMap`, but after I type `java.` I got `no completions found`.

so I guess my question is- how can I import and use the map container properly?

If there is some other data structure (of- key, value) in matlab, its also acceptable.

I will be happy for some guidance, thanks.

Comment: Please provide a *reproducible* example along with the full error message and stack trace

Answer (score 0):

The correct name is `containers.Map`, see [Map Containers](http://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/map-containers.html). Example:

```
>> map = containers.Map('Feb', 1000)

map = 

  Map with properties:

        Count: 1
      KeyType: char
    ValueType: double
```