# How to store all subsets of a given set

Tags: matlab

Good morning, I'm implementing Held-Karp in Matlab, and I'm a bit stuck on how to store the subsets of a given size that are generated by the method.  I'm considering using a map through the containers.map class so that I do not need to generate sequential keys to identify each subset (which I would if I used an array).  However, I need to generate a unique key for each subset which I can use to compute extended paths in the recursive step.  I've considered methods revolving around multiplying all of the elements of the set together to generate a key, but this may not necessarily be unique: within subsets of size two, the sets ${ 6, 3 }$ and ${ 9, 2}$ would map to the same key, which would impact the dynamic programming aspect of the algorithm.  Is there a simple way to hash the subsets and generate unique keys for each set?  Thank you.

Comment: Wouldn't a cell array be sufficient?

Comment: @beaker The thing is this might be prohibitive to search to see if a given subset is in the array.  We'd have to loop over each element of both sets and compare elements, taking linear time.  I believe this would push the complexity from n^2 2^n to n^3 2^2 if I'm not mistaken.  I was hoping for something like a hash function or hash set

Comment: You *could* add a dimension for each of the recursive levels, but yes, that would mean a large search. Binary encoding won't work either, for graphs larger than 64 vertices. I'm not aware of any implemented hash functions other than Map, and as you say, a hash set would be more appropriate.

Comment: Ah, there's always the Java solution: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12625797/1377097