# Reach the value of string elements in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I have an array like this:

```
vars = {'X1','X2'};
```

all the elements in this array have special range such as:

```
X1 = [0.5,11.0];
X2 = [0.15,8.55];
```

Now in a loop I want to reach each elements values (i.e. X1 value is [0.5,11.0]), can you help me pls?

Best,
Elnaz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, one option is to use `eval` to get the values:

```
X1 = [1,2];
X2 = [3,4];
vars = {'X1','X2'};

for ii = 1:length(values)
    vals{ii} = eval(vars{ii});
end
```

Which stores the values in the variable `vals`, i.e. `vals = {[1,2], [3,4]}`.

However, using `eval` is generally a very bad idea. Depending on what you want to do, there is probably a much better way of doing it. For example, you could store the variables you're interested in in a cell array, or as the fields of a structure.

Comment: How can I reach a value of the first or second or third item in my structure? i.e.: vars = {'X1','X2','X3','X4','Y'}; 
X1 = [0.5,11.0];
X2 = [0.15,8.55];
X3 = [1.64,142.5];
X4 = [1.0,165.0];
Y = [64.470001,8546.030273];

res = struct(char(vars(1)),X1,char(vars(2)),X2,char(vars(3)),X3, ...
    char(vars(4)),X4,char(vars(5)),Y); *** I need to reach in a loop a=X1 and b=[0.5,11.0] c=X2 and d=[0.15,8.55]

Answer (score 0):

I would store everything in a structure, but I'm unsure it's what you want:

```
clc,clear all,close all
vars = {'X1','X2'};
X1 = [0.5,11.0];
X2 = [0.15,8.55];
res = struct(char(vars(1)),X1,char(vars(2)),X2
```

then I'd call

```
res.X1
res.X2
```

Comment: Thank you for your prompt reply. Indeed I need something like this: res.char(vars(1))

Comment: I should use loop to access the value of my array elements. In loop I can say i.e. a = vars(i) b = vars(i).value which are refer to a = X1 and b = [0.5,11.0]

Answer (score 0):

You can also try:

```
vars = {'X1','X2'};
X1 = [0.5,11.0];
X2 = [0.15,8.55];

vals = containers.Map(vars,{X1,X2});

vals('X1')
vals('X2')
```

Which I got from Amro's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3591942/hash-tables-in-matlab). This is the output:

```
ans =

    0.5000   11.0000


ans =

    0.1500    8.5500
```