# Change index in matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix, indexing

I'm trying to change the matrix index, by storing values, but I'm not quiet sure how to do it.

I have a matrix imported from Excel, where the values in the first row and column indicating a week number and a zip code. So when I call the function in command window, I would like to be able to write week number and zip code as parameters, instead of the matrix index. Is that possible? And how?

Thank you

Comment: Can you show this with an example? Thanks!

Comment: Have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3591942/hash-tables-in-matlab

Answer (score 1):

You can probably do it with a function like this:

```
function value = GetValue(matrix, date, zipcode)
    r = find(matrix(:, 1) == date);
    c = find(matrix(1, :) == zipcode);
    value = matrix(r,c);
end
```

Comment: Thanks, but what if I wish to use While to run through the column with zip codes, and find the matrix index for the zip code I type in my call. Would that be possible and how?

Thank you

Comment: @NannaLarsen I don't understand your question I'm afraid. With this function you can just enter a date and a zip code and pull out the relevant cell? Is that not what you are trying to do?