# Nonzero elements command with hash tables aka hashmaps in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, hash, hashmap

I need to find out the amount of non-zero elements with [Matlab hashmap/hash-tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3591942/hash-tables-in-matlab), `nnz` does not work with it. For example, `nnz(hhh.values)` does not work. How can I check non-zero elements in Matlab's hashmap?

```
keys = {'Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun'};
values = {327.2, 368.2, 197.6, 178.4, 100.0,  69.9}
hhh = containers.Map(keys, values)
nnz(hhh.values)
```

returns

> Undefined function 'nnz' for input arguments of type 'cell'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, it's a bit ugly, but if you want something compact you can use [`cellfun`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cellfun.html) in conduction with `nnz`:

```
nnz(cellfun(@(x)x~=0,hhh.values))
```

Or you can convert the cell array of scalars to a vector via concatenation provided that everything is of the same class, as is the case in this example (see the `'UniformValues'` option in [`containers.Map`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/containers.mapclass.html)):

```
vals = hhh.values;
nnz([vals{:}])
```