# Issue with output of an indirect equation using Fzero

Tags: matlab, for-loop, iteration, output

I am stuck on trying to write the output of a for loop into a vector. The issue is that once it goes through the equation, it stops and spits out this error: "Subscript indices must either be real positive
integers or logicals."

I've looked into what this error is and I've checked my code. There are no negative integers being output, nor any zeros. The for-loop, function and the fzero command are all good, if I comment out `MW4p(y4,:) = MW4` I get all of my answers on the command window. I just can't put them into an array.

```
for y4 = linspace(1.4,1.67,100)
x0 = 12;     %Starting Point
fun = @(MW4) (y4.*MW1.*T3)./(y1.*MW4.*T2) - ...
        (((1+((y4+1)./(y4-1)).*p5p2).*((2.*y4)./(y4-1))) ./ ((1+...
        ((y1+1)./(y1-1)).*p5p2).*((2.*y1)./(y1-1)))) .* (((2./(y1-1))...
        ./ (2./(y4-1))).^2); 
MW4 = fzero(fun,x0) 
MW4p(y4,:) = MW4
end
```

where

```
y1   = 1.67;
MW1  = 39.55;
T3   = 250;        %k
T2   = 700;        %k
p5p2  = 2.307;     %Determined from T5 desired
MW4p = ones(1,100);
```

In earlier attempts, I've tried `MW4p(y4) = MW4` which had this error: "Attempted to access MW4p(1.4); index must be a
positive integer or logical." So I added a colon. Putting this command outside of the for-loop simply had it access the last value of the loop and return the same error.

Comment: `y4` must be an integer, not a double.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message is telling you exactly what you need to know.  `y4` is *not* an integer.  When using vectors, matrices, cells, or arrays you can't index with a non-integer number.

vectors, matrices and arrays are discrete structures that can only be indexed with discrete values, though obviously they can be used to store non-discrete values.

Unless I'm missing something, your choices are:

- Through whatever data structure: store `y4` and its corresponding `MW4` value as a tuple; for example, you might have an array of structs or cells where one element is `y4` and another element is the array returned from `MW4`
- Use something like [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3592050/549246), using a hash map.  I haven't looked into this closely, but my guess is you can use a float as the key.

Comment: Ok, so if i understand this correctly: I can run the for-loop for non-integer iterations and get a stream of answers, OR I can change y4 to a set of integer numbers and have it indexed correctly, even though MW4=fzero(..) might have doubles as answers.

Comment: I modified my answer.