# Store MATLAB class instance into java.util.HashMap

Tags: matlab

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Storing MATLAB structs in Java objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/436852/storing-matlab-structs-in-java-objects)

I'm currently using [`containers.Map`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/containers_map.html) to associate keys and values in MATLAB.  However, quick tests show that this class is really slow compared to `java.util.HashMap`.  The documentation does not specify the algorithmic complexity for storage and retrieval, so I'm scared it's not using a hash table, and I really need flat performance (O(1) insertion and retrieval).

I've been trying to convert my code using `containers.Map` to `java.util.HashMap`, but it doesn't work when I try to insert custom MATLAB class instances into the hash map.  For instance, given the following class

```
classdef Bucket < handle
    % ... application-specific code ...
end
```

I can't do this:

```
m = java.util.HashMap(); % association.
b = Bucket();            % class instance.
k = ...;                 % some relevant value for association.
m.put(k, b);
```

It fails with the error message:

> ??? No method 'put' with matching signature found for class 'java.util.HashMap'.

The exact same code works if I replace `b` with some non-custom class, such as:

```
b = 'foo';
m.put(k, b);
```

How can I store `Bucket` instances in a `java.util.HashMap`?