# How to gather results with parfor in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I have a function called SpreadFinder which returns an array of structures:

```
[ spreads ] = SpreadFinder( pp, corr_thres, i_range )
```

The return object looks like this:

```
spreads = 
1x4026 struct array with fields:
px
tuple
beta
```

The code is:

```
m = containers.Map(0, 0, 'uniformValues',false); m.remove(0);
parfor col = 1:8
    spreads = SpreadFinder(pp, 0.8, i_ranges(:,col)');
    m(col)  = spreads;
end
```

When I run it, I have this error:

```
Subscripted assignment dimension mismatch.
```

I know the Map can be used to store an array of structures. (https://stackoverflow.com/a/2365526)

This code below works. So I don't think it's a problem of dimension...

```
m(1) = spreads(1:2);
m(2) = spreads(1:4);
```

The objective is to merge all the results into one map and possibly iterate over this map after the parallel task.

Can someone help me out?

Best,

Comment: So did what I write help you solve your problem?

Answer (score 1):

IIRC, you cannot assign to a `containers.Map` inside a `parfor` because a `containers.Map` is not [sliceable](http://www.mathworks.com/help/distcomp/sliced-variables.html).  If you want to assign elements to an array inside a `parfor`, it must be sliceable.  What I mean by sliceable is that you are able to extract a subset of the values via the `colon` operator (i.e. `1:3`, `2:4`), etc.  You cannot do that with a `containers.Map` unless you specifically use the `values` function, and from there you can specify a cell array of keys and get the values from there.  Using `()` syntax only permits you to access one key at a time.

Therefore, what I would suggest you do is assign the outputs to a cell array, and use this cell array as values into your `containers.Map`.  Something like this:

```
%// Create temporary cell array of values
c = cell(1,8);

%// Run parfor for each col
parfor col = 1:8
    c{col} = SpreadFinder(pp, 0.8, i_ranges(:,col)');
end

%// Make a new containers.Map for these values
m = containers.Map(1:8, c, 'uniformvalues', false);
%clear c; %// Optional if you don't want the temporary cell array to stick around
```